How can I attach rain gutter downspout to a steel pole?
I'm trying to control erosion below my deck.
My plan is to add a gutter along the edge of the deck and route the downspout along the pole that's closest to the camera.
How might I attach the downspout to this metal pole?

Also open to any other suggestions to control the erosion below the deck.

Is water actually running off your deck?  The boards look parallel to the house so if the water is just dripping through the boards, a gutter isn't going to help.

The "pole" is a structural post, albeit a steel one. You might want to repaint it while the rust is still superficial.
You can either attach (treated or plastic) lumber to it with U-bolts to use "standard" gutter downspout brackets, or you can attach the downspout to it with plumbing strap or hose clamps. There are surely other ways that will work as well.
The ungrassed area under the deck you can put down geotextile held down with some of the loose rock that's already there to reduce erosion. Once you get the runoff contained in the downspout and away from the area, you can add dirt and seed and burlap to the eroded grassed area. Or sod if the budget is high.
Another option to reduce erosion of the grassed area would be a retaining wall to reduce the slope in that area to 1/8-1/4" per foot (1-2 cm/m) to reduce the velocity of the water flowing off.
If not going with the gutter, a drainage trench where the bulk of the water hits the ground to remove it without it running down the eroded grassed slope. That would probably want geotextile and rocks in it.

Another option may be to place some permanent erosion control matting, with some topsoil and seed, on the eroded area—possibly with some #57 or larger stone right at the dripline.  (It's not clear if the erosion is caused by the dripping, or the runoff.)

Consider a "rain chain" instead, which you could suspend just off the corner of the deck where the gutter ends. That and a splash pad might be both convenient and attractive.

source
